# Execute function multiple times replacing part of argument sequentially

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

I have a method (exampleObj.method) that takes arguments of an object and a function. This is shown below:

```
exampleObj.method({
        name1: 'string1',
        name2: 'string2',
        name3: 'string3',
        name4: {
            array1: ['item1a', 'item1b', 'item1c'],
            array2: ['item2a']
        },
        name5: exampleObj.method2
    },
    function exampleFunc(arg1, arg2) {
        // function logic here
    }
};
```

What I want to achieve is to execute the method multiple times, each time replacing array1 with a different array from the arrayCollection variable in sequence.

```
var arrayCollection = [
    ['item1d', 'item1e', 'item1f'],
    ['item1g', 'item1h', 'item1i'],
    ['item1j', 'item1k', 'item1l']
];
```

I know that I could iterate through the arrayCollection array executing the method each time or perhaps use forEach to achieve the same. What I am struggling with is replacing the value of array1 each time the method is executed.

When I've searched for an answer it seems as if array.map may be an option. I'm not sure how to use this to change the specific array1 value though.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: What problem did you have when iterating arrayCollection?  Setting the array1 property to arrayCollection[i] should work, in the case of a simple for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(const array1 of arrayCollection)
  exampleObj.method({
        name1: 'string1',
        name2: 'string2',
        name3: 'string3',
        name4: {
            array1,
            array2: ['item2a']
        },
        name5: exampleObj.method2
    },
    function exampleFunc(arg1, arg2) {
        // function logic here
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!
I think there is an extra curly bracket on the last line but I've implemented it without that and it works perfectly!
I've tried to give you +1 but don't have enough reputation currently.